# Show First Two Decimal Points .text

Tags: javascript

I made a calculator and it is showing result in many decimal places. How can i restrict it to just two decimal places.

I tried using `.tofixed(3)` but it is not working.

**Working Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/m3hfb37x/

Comment: So where do you use toFixed(3) ?

Comment: did you try to use toFixed(2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`.toFixed(2)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed).

Note that it's `2` (ie, two decimal places) where as your example had `3` for some reason.

Also note the capital F in `toFixed`. Your example shows a lowercased one which would have resulted in an error.

Changing just this line

```
$('#amount').text("$" + result_maker);
```

to

```
$('#amount').text("$" + result_maker.toFixed(2));
```

worked for me.

Comment: O_o It actually Worked!

Comment: Haha don't be too surprised :) You were pretty close.

Comment: One question. How can we make output to show comma/separator  in 1000? like 1,000

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript covers that pretty well. Never be afraid to search for a solution before asking here, this was very easy to find :)